# Как выровнять колонки по большей высоте на css?

Tags: html, css

Верстка должна быть простой блочной, без bootstrap, flex, grid, display-table. Левая колонка должна быть по высоте такая же, как и правая.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .nav {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: #F0E68C;
  }
  .content {
    float: left;
    width: calc(100% - 250px);
    padding: 0 100px 0 50px;
    background-color: blue;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section class="nav">   
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">конькобежный спорт</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">биатлон</a></li>
      </ul>
  </section>
  <section class="content">
    <h1>Футбол</h1>
      <p>Футбо́л (от англ. foot — ступня, ball — мяч) — командный вид спорта, в котором целью является забить мяч в ворота соперника ногами или другими частями тела (кроме рук) большее количество раз, чем команда соперника.</p>
      <p>Есть 17 официальных правил игры, каждое из которых содержит список оговорок и руководящих принципов. Эти правила предназначены для применения на всех уровнях футбола, хотя есть некоторые изменения для таких групп, как юниоры, взрослые, женщины и люди с ограниченными физическими возможностями. Законы очень часто формулировались в общих чертах, которые позволяют упростить их применения в зависимости от характера игры.Правила игры публикуются в ФИФА, но поддерживаются Международным советом футбольных ассоциаций (IFAB)[31].</p>    
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Кроме того предоставленный код и так "без bootstrap, flex, grid, display-table", а что должно получиться, если не то что есть - неясно.

Comment: Левая колонка желтого цвета должна быть по высоте как и правый большой блок с текстом

Comment: без bootstrap, flex, grid, display-table, да без проблем...   возьми карандаш нарисуй на мониторе.....

Answer (score 3):

Copy from SO en:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205159/html-css-making-two-floating-divs-the-same-height

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .container {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .nav {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: #F0E68C;
  }
  .content {
    float: left;
    width: calc(100% - 250px);
    padding: 0 100px 0 50px;
    background-color: blue;
  }
  section.nav, section.content {
    margin-bottom: -500em;
    padding-bottom: 500em;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section class="nav">   
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">конькобежный спорт</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">биатлон</a></li>
      </ul>
  </section>
  <section class="content">
    <h1>Футбол</h1>
      <p>Футбо́л (от англ. foot — ступня, ball — мяч) — командный вид спорта, в котором целью является забить мяч в ворота соперника ногами или другими частями тела (кроме рук) большее количество раз, чем команда соперника.</p>
      <p>Есть 17 официальных правил игры, каждое из которых содержит список оговорок и руководящих принципов. Эти правила предназначены для применения на всех уровнях футбола, хотя есть некоторые изменения для таких групп, как юниоры, взрослые, женщины и люди с ограниченными физическими возможностями. Законы очень часто формулировались в общих чертах, которые позволяют упростить их применения в зависимости от характера игры.Правила игры публикуются в ФИФА, но поддерживаются Международным советом футбольных ассоциаций (IFAB)[31].</p>    
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Без флексов и таблиц остается только имитировать ...

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.nav {
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #F0E68C;
}
.content {
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - 250px);
  padding: 0 100px 0 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

/* Имитация равных колонок */

.container {
  background-color: #F0E68C;
}

.container:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section class="nav">   
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">конькобежный спорт</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">биатлон</a></li>
      </ul>
  </section>
  <section class="content">
    <h1>Футбол</h1>
      <p>Футбо́л (от англ. foot — ступня, ball — мяч) — командный вид спорта, в котором целью является забить мяч в ворота соперника ногами или другими частями тела (кроме рук) большее количество раз, чем команда соперника.</p>
      <p>Есть 17 официальных правил игры, каждое из которых содержит список оговорок и руководящих принципов. Эти правила предназначены для применения на всех уровнях футбола, хотя есть некоторые изменения для таких групп, как юниоры, взрослые, женщины и люди с ограниченными физическими возможностями. Законы очень часто формулировались в общих чертах, которые позволяют упростить их применения в зависимости от характера игры.Правила игры публикуются в ФИФА, но поддерживаются Международным советом футбольных ассоциаций (IFAB)[31].</p>    
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: сколько не живу - всегда стоит сначала поискать по SO, а потом справшивать и отвечать. Можно, еще как можно и без таблиц))

Comment: @Vyacheslav Potseluyko, вижу, пытаюсь понять есть ли у этого способа подвохи, всегда меня смущают фиксированные значения которые берутся непонятно откуда

Comment: это не фиксированное значение фиг знает откуда. Это просто какая-то очень большая константа, так, чтоб точно хватило на высоту второго блока. Не более)

Comment: @Vyacheslav Potseluyko, это не константа. Это просто костыль. В целом, неплохой вариант (в стиле Qwertiy xDDD), но если захочется узнать высоту этого блока через `innerHeight`, ничего хорошего из этого не получится)

Comment: ну да, костыль. Но, строго говоря, Ваш вариант автору не подходит - он просил без display: table. А без этого только костыли и остаются(

Comment: @Vyacheslav Potseluyko, `display: table` - я указал по привычке, почему-то именно его прописывают для `clearfix`, можно спокойно на `display: block` заменить - ничего не изменится.

Comment: Вау, теперь класс:)

Comment: Спасибо за решение! Оно прекрасно работает здесь, но только не у меня((( Посмотрите пожалуйста, я добавил Ваш код в мой, но ничего не работает.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wqZpWe

Comment: для `.content` нужен `background-color` который будет перекрывать фон родителя, в вашей задаче он `background-color: blue;` в вашем примере его нет. В этом и заключается имитация и в этом главная проблема этого метода, если блок который перекрывает содержит мало контента (левая колонка выше чем правая), то имитация ломается, я бы в вашем случае лучше использовал способ предложенный товарищем @Vyacheslav Potseluyko

Comment: Действительно, я здесь для наглядности этот цвет написал, а у меня его не было. Решение товарища @Vyacheslav Potseluyko во-первых мне не понятно, а во-вторых я его добавил и оно не сработало и вообще все сбило. А Ваше сработало. Просто добавил bgc:white. Спасибо!

Comment: @PolonskiyP, его метод прост. обеим колонкам задается огромный `padding` снизу, после чего на этот же размер этот `padding` обрезается через отрицательный `margin`, все что вам надо, что бы работал его метода, это : `.container { overflow: hidden; } .nav, .content { margin-bottom: -500em; padding-bottom: 500em; }`. Вставьте это вместо того что вы вставили из моего варианта и все будет хорошо.

Comment: И да, отметьте верный ответ.